# Python - Django - Input validation

Tags: python, django, validation, input

How can I make a validation for post fetch input? I manually validate if the first digit has empty space or isalnum to make update operation as below but I wonder is there a better approach?

```
def update_user_meta(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
    name = request.POST.get("name")
    if name is not None and name[0:1].isalnum() == True:
            selectedUser.name = name
    else:
            selectedUser.name = selectedUser.name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are built-in functions to make field validations. It can be done with Regex Validator.

List of them are in the documents.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/validators/

Answer (score 0):

You should use django forms
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/.

Unless this view is an API then use the serializers from the django rest framework.
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/

Comment: but I use React Native.

Comment: so u should use https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/

Comment: Example of validation:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation

Comment: I just saw django built-in validators. It works for me. Please add this to your answer and to choose as correct answer. docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/validators

Comment: @nogabemist validators should be used in forms, models or serializers not directly in views

Comment: The question is not related with form validator. It is about string validator. Check out the link that I give. It is in the documents. Validating string is not problem.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/validators/#how-validators-are-run
The best approach is to use a form / serializer and add the appropriate validations there.

Comment: The best approact is not to use a form for field validation. If you want flexibility and more customization you don't have to stick with form. This question is about only field validation. Not related with form or serializing.